# Mule twitter - statuses update v 1.1 not working

Tags: twitter, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to connect to twitter 1.1 REST api for statuses update but get the following exception :

```
Root Exception stack trace:
twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["text"] not found.
    at twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:395)
    at twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:509)
    at twitter4j.internal.json.StatusJSONImpl.init(StatusJSONImpl.java:166)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

Please help me solve this.
I am using Mule Studio 3.4 CE.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding an Object-To-JSON transformer ***after*** the twitter flow component.